# How do I make a javascript link open to share a different link for seo purposes?

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, custom-controls, share, facebook-social-plugins

Hi I'd like to share a link different to a web page I'm sharing from.
It goes to the same page but its a tiny url link. The below code share the page url to Facebook and Twitter, but how do I share a custom link?

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=copy goes in here&url=http://PAGE_URL" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="images/transbg.png" id="twit_sprite" width="1" height="1" /></a>


<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://PAGE_URL&t=copy goes in here" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="images/transbg.png" id="fb_sprite" width="1" height="1" /></a>
```

Comment: If I understand you question right, you want to go from www.domain1.com to www.domain2.com so just add http:// in the begging of address.

Comment: Sorry Kamen Thanks for trying but that's not what I'm asking its a complicated social media javascript issue built into the link.

Comment: Ah got it just add it into the PAGE_URL attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah got it just add it into the PAGE_URL attribute